# How do I tell the maven pmd plugin to ignore 'Avoid unused private fields such as ...` when using lombok?

Tags: maven, lombok, pmd

I have a simple domain class like this...

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Address
{
    private String purpose;
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    ....
}
```

But when I run `mvn clean package org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:3.6:check`, I get the following warnings...

> Avoid unused private fields such as 'purpose'.

What is the proper way to tell the PMD plugin to ignore these?

My `pmd-rules.xml` Looks like...

```
<ruleset xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="Default Maven PMD Plugin Ruleset" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>
        Excluding rules.
    </description>
    <rule ref="category/java/bestpractices.xml">
        <exclude name="UnusedPrivateMethod"/>
    </rule>
</ruleset>
```

And the following in my pom...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/java/maven-pmd-plugin-default.xml</ruleset>
                    <ruleset>pmd-rules.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I do this I get no results. There is a parent maven project that had initially configured this plugin.

Comment: Please check the docs: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html

Comment: I had looked at that, since that was your response I added my PDM.xml. I thought Maven defaulted to look for this but it isn't helping

Comment: I also looked at the ruleset configuration link which is closer to what I want to do but I would prefer to keep things separate from my pom file.

Comment: You can put the rulset file separately from your pom file ... (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) ... ?

Comment: Added more info then per the link provided I tried moving to my resource folder but then it can't find the file when I try to override the parent plugin config.

Comment: I also tried changing the filename to ruleset and putting it in resources it while removing it from the pom. That just goes back to not ignoring the Private var issues.